# Webpshere MQ temporary dynamic queues using Model queues

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using the following sample code to create a temporary replyto queue

```
final TemporaryQueue replyQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
message.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);
producer.send(destination, message);
```

This uses a default model queue `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE` to create the temporary dynamic queue.

Please just want to know if there is way to use my own model queue instead of using the default model queue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the JavaDoc for the MQConnectionFactory - there's a model queue property on the connection factory that controls this.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/index.html

Comment: Thanks Calanis.<bean id="mqClientConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
  ...
          p:temporaryModel="MQ.QM"
          p:tempQPrefix="MQ.*">
</bean>

Also found out if setting conenction factories in Websphere Applicaiton server, I can set the model queus and temp queues in the additional settings of the queue connection factories of WAS.